# How to check if Emacs is in GUI mode (and execute `tool-bar-mode` only then)?

Tags: mac-osx, emacs

I have this line in my `.emacs` file:

```
(tool-bar-mode 0)
```

because I hate the toolbars in my GUI emacs (`/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`).

But when I start up my other, text-based emacs in the terminal (`/opt/local/bin/emacs`) it complains about that command:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: tool-bar-mode
```

How can I add an `if` condition so that it executes the `tool-bar-mode` command only when I'm in the GUI emacs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Okay, found it myself. Just add

```
;; turn off toolbar
(if window-system
    (tool-bar-mode 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

another way to do it would be:

```
 (if (functionp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode 0))
```

like this, the function is called only if it exists

Answer (score 0):

It works for me without complaint on Linux. You might try `nil` or `-1` instead of `0`:

```
(tool-bar-mode nil)
```

What happens if you do `emacs -nw`?

Answer (score 0):

Use of the `window-system` variable as a boolean is *deprecated*.  Instead,
use `display-graphic-p` or any of the other `display-*-p`
predicates which report frame’s specific UI-related capabilities.

In case you want your code to be backward-compatible with the previous versions of Emacs, then the following compatibility wrapper is the way to go:

```
(if (< emacs-major-version 23)
    (or window-system (getenv "DISPLAY"))
  (display-graphic-p))
```